# Framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode

This error is very weird.Everything is just fine yesterday.I install the Xcode 9 beta, and then I use Xcode 8 to run my app on iPhone 6p, iOS 9.3.2(I can do this yesterday, and I can still run the app on the simulator)then I get this error.

I Googled the error, it seems like no one runs into this error before.

Here is the error log:

> Ld
>   /Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Global\
>   Domain.app/Global\ Domain normal arm64 cd
>   /Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>   export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain -L/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/GDWeChatPay -L/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK/Support/PlatformSDK/WeChatSDK
>   -L/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon -L/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk -F/Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK/Support/Optional
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK/Support/PlatformSDK/QQSDK
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK/Support/Required
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/MobileAnalytics
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/GDAlipaySDK -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/TencentIM -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/UMeng -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/ShareSDK/Support/PlatformConnector
>   -F/Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon -filelist /Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Intermediates/GlobalDomain.build/Debug-iphoneos/Global\
>   Domain.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Global\ Domain.LinkFileList -Xlinker
>   -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Intermediates/GlobalDomain.build/Debug-iphoneos/Global\
>   Domain.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Global\ Domain_lto.o -Xlinker
>   -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lCYLTabBarController -lFMDB -lIQKeyboardManager -lMBProgressHUD -lMJRefresh -lMasonry -lsqlite3 -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration
>   -framework UIKit -framework StoreKit -framework Security -lz -framework CoreTelephony -framework Crashlytics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreLocation
>   -framework AdSupport -framework UMMobClick -lGDTMobSDK -lsqlite3 -framework JavaScriptCore -lstdc++ -framework TencentOpenAPI -licucore -lresolv -framework UserNotifications -framework UIKit -framework MOBFoundation -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   CoreFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework IMCore -framework ImSDK
>   -framework IMSDKBugly -framework ShareSDKUI /Users/tianchi/Desktop/ios/trunk/GlobalDomain/GDCommon/jpush-ios-2.2.0.a
>   -framework QALHttpSDK -framework WechatConnector -framework ShareSDK -framework QALSDK -framework QQConnector -framework TLSSDK -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework ShareSDKConnector -framework
>   MessageUI -framework ImageIO -lWeChatSDK -framework Fabric -framework
>   AlipaySDK -lWeChatSDK -framework ShareSDKExtension -lc++ -lPods
>   -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Intermediates/GlobalDomain.build/Debug-iphoneos/Global\
>   Domain.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Global\ Domain_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/tianchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobalDomain-dxjnqhelcuqfqkgiqyycgpwmzail/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Global\
>   Domain.app/Global\ Domain
>
> ld: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right click on your new **Xcode9-Beta**.app and select *Show Package Contents*

Then navigate to:

```
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Then go to this same folder in the package contents of your **Xcode8.app** and paste the required framework(s) there.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this bug goes away for no reason……, anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @Luis , how did you find the answer?

Comment: @allenlinli, the error states that a framework is missing, so I just looked at the new Xcode's framework to see if the missing framework was there...

Comment: saved my life, not sure what is going on, but this solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Had the same issue with you, and actually I needed to copy `FileProvider.framework` and `IOSurface.framework` to Xcode8

Comment: After updating the pod, same issue arises.FileProvider not found while running on simulator and IOSurface not found while running on device.Can someone explain why it is happening??

Comment: It is a little bit weird. I checked the projectfile and no reference to those 2 files are defined. Looks like some Magic to be forced to use xcode 9.

Comment: the way canot to appStore，iTunes connet  error " non-public API usage"  "FileProvider.framework and IOSurface.framework"

Comment: I did followed the steps given by you, but still same error happening.

Comment: I am still getting this issue :(

Answer (score 4):

After installing the Xcode9 Beta, you did very likely change your default Xcode with `xcode-select -s ...`. That made the `framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64` error pop up when building with Xcode8.3.3 for me.

To fix this, I simply executed:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`

with `/Applications/Xcode.app` being the Xcode8.x version.

Comment: Did not worked for me. You can switch this setting in XCode preferences as well. Does not helps either.
Answer by Luis worked.

Comment: It depends on which Xcode and which SDK you're using to build an app. It works with Xcode 8.3.3 and iOS SDK 10.3. Validated this on several machines, also with my colleagues. Please check your setup and build settings. Also check if `xcodebuild -version` prints something with `8.3.*`

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have previously built this project using Xcode 9 (beta, GM or the final release) and re-opened this same project on Xcode 8 and are now trying to build it again.

If you "Clean your build folder" (hold option and click on the Product menu on Xcode), you should be ready to do a fresh build on Xcode 8, without copying any frameworks from Xcode 9.

At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i fix it,you must use Xcode8 build you use framework,because Xcode9 don't have this framework

Comment: "FileProvider.framework and IOSurface.framework"  is system framework in Xcode9， way build error with  no use framework in Xcode8?

Answer (score 0):

maybe reason `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK` link framework or static libraries, in `Build Settings` 中 `Link Frameworks Automatically` default `Yes` to `No`。

[XCode’s New “Link Frameworks Automatically” & How to Fix “framework not found Metal for architecture armv7”](https://mmmag.appsee.com/2014/09/22/xcode-new-link-frameworks-automatically-fix-framework-not-found-metal-for-architecture-armv7/)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue by installing two versions of Xcode. My solution is reopening the project with lower version Xcode, then remove and add the relative frameworks.